# How to efficiently store multiple different counter values on a user in a MySQL based application?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store different kinds of counters for my user. 
Platform: Java

E.g. I have identified:

- currentNumRecords
- currentNumSteps
- currentNumFlowsInterval1440
- currentNumFlowsInterval720
- currentNumFlowsInterval240
- currentNumFlowsInterval60
- currentNumFlowsInterval30
- etc.

Each of the counters above needs to be reset at the beginning of each month for each user. The value of each counter can be unpredictably high with peaks etc. (I mean that a lot of things are counted, so I want to think about a scalable solution).

Now my question is what approach to take to:

**a)** Should I have separate columns for each counter on the user table and doing things like 'Update set counterColumn = counterColumn+ 1' ?

**b)** put all the values in some kind of JSON/XML and put it in a single column? (in this case I always have to update all values at once)

The disadvantage I see is row locking on the user table everytime a single counter is incremented.

**c)** having an separate counter table with 3 columns (userid, name, counter) and doing one INSERT for each count + having a background job doing aggregates which are written to the User table? In this case would it be ok to store the aggregated counters as JSON inside a column in the user table?

**d)** Doing everything in MySQL or also use another technology? I also thought about using another solution for storing counters and only keeping the aggregates in MySQL. E.g. I have experimented with Apache Cassandra's distributed counters. My concerns are about the Transactions which cassandra does not have.
I need the counters to be exact because they are used for billing, thus I don't know if Cassandra is a good fit here, although the scalability of Cassandra seems tempting. 
What about Redis for storing the counters + writing the aggregates in MySQL? Does Redis have stuff which helps me here? Or should I just store everything in a simple Java HashMap in-memory and have a aggregation background thread and don't use another technology?

In summary I am concerned about:

- reduce row locking
- have exact counters (transactions?)

Thanks for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of saying contradictory things.

> The number of counts can be huge or at least unpredictable per user.

To me this means they must be uniform, like an array.  It is not possible to have an unbounded number of heterogenous data, unless you have an unbounded amount of code and an unbounded number of developer hours to expend.

If they are uniform they should be flattened into a table user_counter where each row is of the form `(user_id, counter_name, counter_value)`.  However you will need to think carefully about what sort of indices you will need, etc.  Updating at the beginning of the month if they are all set to zero or some default value is one SQL query.

Basically (c). (a) and (b) are most absurd and MySQL is still a suitable technology for this.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. The counters are uniform. I just wanted to say that the counter values can be unpredictably high. What I wanted to say is that there is lots of counting going on with peaks, so I was looking for a solution which can be scaled for high traffic.

Comment: Dealing with unboundedly large counters is a very different question but I'm guessing you can come up with a reasonable bound and use an appropriate data type (64 bit long?).  I don't know how to handle true unbounded numbers in MySQL.  I would recommend trying to break this design question down into separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not so untypical. In general this is statistical session/user/... bound written data.

The first thing is to split things if not already done so. Make a mostly readonly database, and separately collect these data. So a separated user table for the normal properties.

The statistical data could be held in an in-memory table. You could also use means other than a database, a message queue, session attributes.